# Adding company name to \maketitle

Tags: titles

How can I add the name of my company to the title generated by `\maketitle`?
The example is [here](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/es/us/archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf).

Comment: How about `\date{Blackhole Generators Ltd. \\ \today}`? There is no `company` field for the title by default. This deliberately depends on the class and on additional packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty hack of `\@maketitle` command by adding the content of `\@company`, which is set with `\company` as is done for `\title` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\company}[1]{\gdef\@company{#1}}
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    \@ifundefined{@company}{}{%
      {\Large \sffamily \@company \par}%
      \vskip 1em%
      \let\@company\relax%
    }%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}

\makeatother

\title{Theory on Brontosaurs}
\company{Blackhole Generators Ltd. \\ CERN, Geneva}

\author{Ann Elk (Misses)}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See also the `titling` package